# sql::connection vs QSqlDatabase

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

I have a library class that holds a pointer to an `sql::Connection` as

```
class A { 
  std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> conn;
  ...
}
```

and the methods of A do use `conn`. 
I am writing a QT5 client for this library and would like to add some methods to `A` by inheriting from it as in `class B : public A`. The preferred method to connect to a database in QT is by using `QSqlDatabase` instead.

What is the right approach in this situation? one option would be to just use connector++ and avoid using `QSqlDatabase`. But I don't know if it's possible to have `B` hold a `QSqlDatabase` and recast it somehow to an `sql::Connection` for the methods in `A`.

Comment: I would just stick to your `sql::Connection` imo it creates confusion if you utilize both

Comment: Why do you think you need a QSqlDatabase in the first place?